# Solr - example spell checker not working

Tags: search, solr, spell-checking

I have set up the spellchecker for the example installation configuration that comes with Solr. I have followed their instructions for the spellchecker here: [http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent][1]

The problem I have is that after following it exactly I still cannot get it to work?

The response when I build (http://localhost:8983/solr/spell?q=*:*&spellcheck.build=true&spellcheck.q=delll%20ultrashar&spellcheck=true)

looks as follows:

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">14</int>
    </lst>
        <str name="command">build</str>
        <result name="response" numFound="17" start="0">
        ...
        </result>
        <lst name="spellcheck">
        <lst name="suggestions"/>
    </lst>
</response>
```

And when I query with http://localhost:8983/solr/spell?q=*:*&spellcheck.q=delll+ultrashar&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.extendedResults=true

I get the following response

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">1</int>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="17" start="0">
    ...
    </result>
    <lst name="spellcheck">
        <lst name="suggestions">
        <bool name="correctlySpelled">false</bool>
        </lst>
    </lst>
</response>
```

What gives? Am i missing something in my schema.xml?

The schema.xml is here: http://www.developermill.com/schema.xml

The solrConfig.xml is here: http://www.developermill.com/solrconfig.xml

The only change to the example files was the addition of the following in the solrconfig.xml:

```
 <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">

  <lst name="spellchecker">
    <!--
        Optional, it is required when more than one spellchecker is configured.
        Select non-default name with spellcheck.dictionary in request handler.
    -->
    <str name="name">default</str>
    <!-- The classname is optional, defaults to IndexBasedSpellChecker -->
    <str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str>
    <!--
        Load tokens from the following field for spell checking,
        analyzer for the field's type as defined in schema.xml are used
    -->
    <str name="field">spell</str>
    <!-- Optional, by default use in-memory index (RAMDirectory) -->
    <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
    <!-- Set the accuracy (float) to be used for the suggestions. Default is 0.5 -->
    <str name="accuracy">0.7</str>
    <!-- Require terms to occur in 1/100th of 1% of documents in order to be included in the dictionary -->
    <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.0001</float>
  </lst>
  <!-- Example of using different distance measure -->
  <lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="name">jarowinkler</str>
    <str name="field">lowerfilt</str>
    <!-- Use a different Distance Measure -->
    <str name="distanceMeasure">org.apache.lucene.search.spell.JaroWinklerDistance</str>
    <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>

  </lst>

  <!-- This field type's analyzer is used by the QueryConverter to tokenize the value for "q" parameter -->
  <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>
</searchComponent>
<!--
    The SpellingQueryConverter to convert raw (CommonParams.Q) queries into tokens.  Uses a simple regular expression
    to strip off field markup, boosts, ranges, etc. but it is not guaranteed to match an exact parse from the query parser.

Optional, defaults to solr.SpellingQueryConverter
-->
<queryConverter name="queryConverter" class="solr.SpellingQueryConverter"/>

<!--  Add to a RequestHandler
     !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
     NOTE:  YOU LIKELY DO NOT WANT A SEPARATE REQUEST HANDLER FOR THIS COMPONENT.  THIS IS DONE HERE SOLELY FOR
     THE SIMPLICITY OF THE EXAMPLE.  YOU WILL LIKELY WANT TO BIND THE COMPONENT TO THE /select STANDARD REQUEST HANDLER.
     !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
-->
<requestHandler name="/spellCheckCompRH" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <!-- Optional, must match spell checker's name as defined above, defaults to "default" -->
    <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
    <!-- omp = Only More Popular -->
    <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
    <!-- exr = Extended Results -->
    <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>
    <!--  The number of suggestions to return -->
    <str name="spellcheck.count">1</str>
  </lst>
  <!--  Add to a RequestHandler
       !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
       REPEAT NOTE:  YOU LIKELY DO NOT WANT A SEPARATE REQUEST HANDLER FOR THIS COMPONENT.  THIS IS DONE HERE SOLELY FOR
       THE SIMPLICITY OF THE EXAMPLE.  YOU WILL LIKELY WANT TO BIND THE COMPONENT TO THE /select STANDARD REQUEST HANDLER.
       !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  -->
  <arr name="last-components">
    <str>spellcheck</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: Could you please paste here the relevant parts of your `solrconfig.xml` and `schema.xml`?

Comment: Here are the links to the two. The character limit here is to little to paste. 
http://www.developermill.com/solrconfig.xml
http://www.developermill.com/schema.xml

--> The only change I had made was to the solrconfig.xml that is begins with <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent"><lst name="spellchecker"> right at the bottom

Comment: I noticed that the linked `solrconfig.xml` is different from the one pasted in your question. Which one are you using? Maybe you should keep in the question just that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `textSpell` field definition is in the wrong place. The following fragment should be within the `types` tag inside the `schema.xml`:

```
<fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true"  expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

After you've fixed that, everything should work I guess, but I'd suggest you to work on cleaning up a little bit your example, since it basically contains everything you can configure. You should keep just what you really need.

Comment: Thanks Javanna, I corrected my document as you indicated above. That was one of the problems. However I had encountered another problem - that is that the build query fails to build ??

To resolve this I had to include <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
in my searchComponent. Anyone know why the build query fails?

Comment: Have you found any error within your log file? It's strange because the index is built the same way. What you've changed is the moment when it's built. Previously it was built manually, actually it's automatically built after every commit.